# Why can I forward email without mx record set up properly?

Tags: network, internet

Say I have a domain

domain.com

I do not set anything on mx record in domain.com

Yet I can set a forwarder from say hello@domain.com to another email.

I set a address.

Is this normal?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), the target host can be identified by an MX record (which is the rule) but it can also simply be the domain's A record (clause
5.1. *Locating the Target Host*):

> If an empty list of MXs is returned, the address is treated as if
> it was associated with an implicit MX RR, with a preference of 0, pointing to that host.